# How can release unused resource.Thread( OkHttp ConnectionPool ) in OkHttp

Tags: java, okhttp

I am invoking evictAll from connectionPool and cancelAll from dispatchers.
but it is not killing the thread ( OkHttp ConnectionPool ).

**Here is the Thread stacktrace.**

```
[info]java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[info] java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:460)
[info] okhttp3.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:66)
[info] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[info] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[info] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

is there any option to kill these threads ?

okhttp build:- 3.7.0

Comment: Did you wait 60 seconds for the executor service to release them?

Comment: Yes, After 6 minutes they released. how can i configure this time?

Comment: @sewak do you have any updates on this? I've encountered the same problem here.